# AngularJS Custom Google Maps directive with error: 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I would like to create a simple directive in AngularJS that displays a Google Maps according to a location.

I´m getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

I have created next plunker to reproduce the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fnmanw1sjblKTJNmYGaV?p=preview

Comment: usually it is suggested to include code also here on SO, in case the external reference to code is not available anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);
```

To this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
```